# buld a package using make

Tags: apt, make

I am trying to install a package for rnaseq called STAR in a docker container using ubuntu:16.04.

After downloading it and unpacked it I compiled it following the doc:

```
# Compile
cd STAR/source
make STAR
```

Apart for few warnings It seems that the build goes through.

But If I type:

```
STAR
bash: STAR: command not found
```

Yet, looking for it:

```
apt list --installed | grep "STAR"
```

no output...

If I try to recompile:

```
make STAR
make: 'STAR' is up to date.
```

Where my package ended up? Any help?

Comment: `make` does not create a package, so the program, even if correctly installed (see the answer), won’t be visible in `apt list`.

Answer (score 1):

*Usually*, you have to give the command `make install` or similar to, well, **install** the package on your system.

Also, *usually* again, it will go under `/usr/local/` which might **not** be in your `$PATH`, so you need to check the documentation more thoroughly.

If you're looking to create a `.deb` package, check the `dpkg-buildpackage` command from `dpkg-dev`, which you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

This way, you can then use `dpkg -i generated_package_name.deb` to install on your system, and it will appear in `dpkg --list` and `apt list --installed` output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, on the github repo (https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR) there is no mention of `make install`. and If I try to run it I get: `'mv' STAR STARlong ../bin
mv: cannot stat 'STARlong': No such file or directory
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1`

Comment: @diegus the precompiled binaries appear to be in a subdirectory `bin/Linux_x86_64` (or `bin/Linux_x86_64_static` if you want the statically linked version). I expect that's where `make` places them as well.